# Understanding evaluate function in OBIEE

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, business-intelligence, obiee

I read some stuff on OBIEE Evaluate function and could not really understand as I am new to this.

```
EVALUATE('GetValue(%1,''SELECT MAX(P3_LST37) INTO :strValue FROM MV_ITEMSX WHERE ITEM_NUMBER = XXXX '' )' AS VARCHAR(2000), "Product")
```

Can you please help me to  understand the function describe above?

Thanks

Comment: %1 will be replaced with item "Product". This Function is giving you opportunity to use stored functions or Built-in functions in OBIEE.

Answer (score 0):

The Evaluate function enables you to send a function to the database to evaluate and return data to OBIEE. For security purposes you must use references in the function rather than the values themselves.

For example, if I have a column "Core"."Date" which returns the date as a string and want to use the TO_DATE function of evaluate, I would issue the following evaluate expression:

EVALUATE('TO_DATE(%1,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS DATE',"Core"."Date")

Hope that helps.